# Exposing messaging queue to web clients?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, scalability, system-design

Consider a real-time application where a web-client makes a persistent connection to some entity X.

The possible options we have here is:

1. connection to web server which then sends messages to a message queue.
   In this case, entity X equals some web server which then forwards that message to a message queue.

```
                   |=Backend=             
(client) ----------|-(web server)-----------(messageq)------> process message
                   |             ^--backchannel connection
```

2. direct connection to a message queue.
   In this case, web client directly connects to message queue endpoint and pushes messages.

```
                   |=Backend=
(client) ----------|-(messageq)------> process message
                   |
```

What is the recommended best practice here? Where does the message queue sit in **standard enterprise architectures**? Also, if you know of a best practice please share how you come to learn that information (what resources / book contains this knowledge?). Thank you.

Comment: I suspect the right thing to do here is option #2 as otherwise, you will be coupled your client to a certain message queue tool which might not be desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When the client is a web-browser:**

Let me do some Q&A, based on which your question may get answered

**Q1:** Do we expose application Database to our clients, for simple read operations?

**A1:**  No, we want to control what is exposed to the client

**Q2:** Based on Q1, does it makes sense to expose messaging-queue to the client?

**A2:** No, for the same reasons as A2.

**When the messaging-queue is exposed to the WebClient:**

**Q1:** What will happen if the messaging queue provider needs to be changed from let's say Rabbit-Mq to Kafka?

**A1:** Old mobile applications will break. Web-Client needs to be changed in order to compatible with the new queue. (**Bad architecture**)

**Q2:** Can someone tap into another topic/queue as well with-in the same messaging-queue ?

**A2:** Yes (**Bad architecture**)

**When the client is another service:**

Inter-service communication using shared messaging-queue is a pattern used for async-communication by many applications.